# Connecting two monitors to MacBook Pro 2017 while charging it

Tags: display, battery, thunderbolt, charging, hdmi

I am using a 13" MacBook Pro 2017 with a Shinevi Hyperdrive adapter for access to a wider variety of ports, granting my access to a single Thunderbolt 3 port, a USB Type-C port, and a single HDMI port.

While fully charged, I can connect both of my Samsung S22C300 monitors with no problem, one through the HDMI port, and the other through the Thunderbolt 3 port. (**Note**: The single Thunderbolt 3 port is the only port that allows you to charge the MacBook through the Shinevi hyperdrive). This configuration allows me to use 3 screens in total, including the MacBook Pro screen.

However, when my laptop starts running low on battery, I have to unplug the external monitor connected to the Thunderbolt 3 port in order to charge my laptop, leaving me with only one external monitor.

I'd recently bought an HDMI splitter (I have no idea what model splitter it is) in hopes of connecting both monitors through the splitter, but neither monitor is receiving signal through the splitter. I have also checked to see if the splitter is broken by testing it on other devices, and it works elsewhere.

can I charge and have HDMI out from one thunderbolt port?

Comment: Can we presume you only have two thunderbolt ports on your MacBook? Otherwise this makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

One solution for the problem here is to use a **Apple USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter**. It is available on Apple Retail Stores and Apple Online Store for **$69.00**.

[image]

[image]

**Product Description**:

Here's a summary of the product description as obtained from the Apple Online Store [web-page](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1K2AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter):

> The USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter lets you connect your USB-C or Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) enabled Mac to an HDMI display, while also connecting a standard USB device and a USB-C charging cable.

Comment: Those work great. Be sure to disconnect it when you don’t have power in. It’s a small computer to drive the HDMI that boots an os each time you plug it in. (Hence the size)

Comment: So that solves a single monitor but not two...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only solution is the [Hyperdrive](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/hyperdrive-usb-c-hub-for-macbook-pro-2016-2017#/)

From a review:

> Plus the hub’s Thunderbolt 3 port can pipe 100W of power, meaning you
>   can plug in and charge your MacBook Pro at full pelt via the accessory
>   – even the 15-inch MacBook Pro only requires 87W – while having two
>   displays hooked up - [techradar.com](https://www.techradar.com/news/hyperdrive-hub-lets-you-connect-two-monitors-to-your-macbook-pro)

Comment: The *only* solution?

Comment: *that I have found thus far